# apex: query from a list

Tags: apex, soql

I'm using apex and salesforce stuff. I have a list of some accounts and now I need to create another list of the accounts that are valid. so imagine this is the list:

```
 List<Account__c> accounts = [Select Name, Status From Account__c];
 .
 .
 .
 // now I need a new list with all the accounts that the status == 'valid'

 //this is not working
 List<Account__c> accounts = [Select Name, Status From :accounts
                              where status == 'valid'];
```

Is there a way to get the list ?
I don't want to hit the database on the second query.

Comment: unfortunately u cannot SOQL on collections (if u r coming from .NET there is no LINQ equivalent in APEX) so u hv to run a loop to filter out

Comment: Is this still true? No Linq equivalent in Apex. Would you do a for loop then? Is that the current best practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also a good library called [Selector](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector) that helps with this sort of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

You can go through the first list in loop

```
List<Account> validAccounts = new List<Account)();
for (Account acc: accounts) {
    if (acc.Status == 'valid') {
        validAccount.add(acc);
    }
}
```